# Can't add visual page as component on dashboard

Tags: visualforce, reporting, dashboard

Hello it seems that I cannot add a visual page in a dashboard although it was in the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm

but I cant find the option to select a visual page as a component and only reports are visible so is this something that is no longer available ?

Comment: Are you using Salesforce classic or lightning experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can use visual force page as component in Dashboard But it should follow the below as per [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm).

> Visualforce pages that use the Standard Controller can’t be used in dashboards. To be included in a dashboard, a Visualforce page must have either no controller, use a custom controller, or reference a page bound to the StandardSetController Class. If a Visualforce page does not meet these requirements, it does not appear as an option in the dashboard component Visualforce Page drop-down list.

But the above only works in Classic. It does not work in lightning or you cannot add visual force page as component in lightning.